# Oracle application - files missing in the Mount point

Tags: unix, oracle-apps, oracleapplications

My oracle  application test instance  is down, When I browse through the Unix server, I couldn’t find any files in the mount point,U01 U06 or U10, when I  put  BDF command it shows the following

```
$ bdf
Filesystem          kbytes    used   avail %used Mounted on
/dev/vg00/lvol3     204800   35571  158662   18% /
/dev/vg00/lvol1     299157   38506  230735   14% /stand
/dev/vg00/lvol8    1392640 1261068  123620   91% /var
/dev/vg00/lvol7    1327104  825170  470631   64% /usr
/dev/vg00/lvol4     716800  385891  310746   55% /tmp
/dev/vg00/lvol6     872448  814943   53936   94% /opt
/dev/vg00/lvolssh    32768   13243   18306   42% /opt/openssh
/dev/vg00/lvol5     204800  187397   16334   92% /home
/dev/vg00/lvolback  512000  472879   36704   93% /backup
dg-ora04:/dgora03_u10
                    204800  167088   35416   83% /u10
dg-ora04:/dgora03_u06
                    204800  167088   35416   83% /u06
dg-ora04:/dgora03_u01
                    204800  167088   35416   83% /u01
```

Please let me Know why I cant see any files inside the mount points.

Comment: Not a programming question, please post to http://serverfault.com/ . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you see no files, consider running fsck on the filesystem.   The file metadata has a problem.   Also, the lost+found directory may have lots of those files listed in it after fsck runs.

Are these file devices presented on a lun?  You may have to play with the volume manager to get things back on track.

Plus, the root cause of your problem is probably: The files look like they are NFS mounts - which, BTW, is a colossal non-no as far as oracle is concerned.  Even with NFS 4, you can get into a lot of pain using remote mounted filesystems with oracle file I/O drivers.